# web apps - update configuration via API

Tags: azure, api, httprequest, azure-functions, azure-webapps

I would like to change the application settings of an azure functions via API. I have found this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateconfiguration#corssettings) For this API I generate such a body:

```
{
"properties": 
 {
  "appSettings":[
     {
      "Name":"452bb"
     }
   ]
 }
 }
```

After sending my request I get `Response Code: 200` but the value of `Name` doesn't change in Application settings of the Azure functions

Do you have any idea, why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: Have you tried 'name' as small caps? I haven't used the API before, just purely  basing it on the API reference.

Comment: yes I do, but doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Suppose what you need is [Update Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings), I try this this could update the application settings.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/appsettings?api-version=2019-08-01
```

Body

```
    {
  "id": "subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{WebAppName}/config/appsettings",
  "name": "appsettings",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "South Central US",
  "tags": {
    "hidden-related:/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{groupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/tomfreePlan": "empty"
  },
  "properties": {

    "Test1": "testValue1" //Added value
  }
}
```

And before update the settings, you could use [List Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings) post way to list the appsetting body firstly.

As for the api you post, this appsettings I check the resource explorer, it's under the web tag and the appsettings you want it's the first tag shown in the below pics. And I try to just change it in the resource explorer, it doesn't show any error however the value still keep null, so just use the Update Application Settings API

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tested this API, but the problem is now, that It deletes other values in my app settings. Also after calling this api I have a new application settings with only one key/value

Comment: Yes, check this api description, Replaces the application settings of an app, so I said before update list the settings use these settings update it.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunattly it doesnt help me, I would like to change only one key/value

Comment: Have to say for now the API doesn't support this, if you want to implement it you have to use code to do it, there are some SDK to manage it.

Comment: And this API could change only one key/value, it just need to include other settings.

Comment: but what about another API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateconfiguration#corssettings), why it doesn't change values?

Comment: Please try this API.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/update#corssettings

Comment: In a personal guess, the appsettings and other configuration under the web tag it's a default web settings, while there are custom settings, it will be replaced, then have to use the config/appsettings and other settings.

Comment: I have another suspicion: In Azure Resource Explorer --> appsetting on the top action (POST, DELETE) is disabled for me. Maybe it is the reason why it doesn't work for me

Comment: No, my (POST, DELETE) is disabled too, just click Edit and PUT, it will update it however under web tag it won't save it.

Comment: So just use [Web Apps - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/update), it also support update the appsettings, however it also replace the settings. The format should be `{
"properties":{
"siteConfig":{
"appsettings":[
     {
      "Name":"testkey",
"Value":"testvalue"
     }
   ]
}
}
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't like to replace the whole appsettings

Comment: That's why I say first list settings the update. Anyway, if this could help you, please accept it answer.Thanks!

Comment: How to authenticate without oauth and use secret instead?